# ES6 deep nested object destructuring

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an object called `this.props` which contains

```
{
 actions: Object,
 dirty: false,
 form: "Statement",
 autofill: function(),
 **statement: Object**
}
```

`statement` contains

```
{
 firstName: "John"
 lastName: "Peter"
 isConfirmed: true
}
```

I would like to extract `statement` object and the `isConfirmed` property in the same line using es6 destructuring

I've tried

```
const { statement: isConfirmed, isAdmin } = this.props
```

which I get an error when I do `let a = isConfirmed, b = statement`

Answer (score 182, accepted):

> I would like to extract statement object and the isConfirmed property in the same line

```
const { statement: { isConfirmed }, statement } = this.props;
```

That way you get both `isConfirmed` and the whole `statement` object.

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring

Comment: Can you still rename `statement`?

Comment: @carkod yes, `statement: newName`

Comment: @zerkms `const {state : {data}} : {state : any} = useLocation();` this statement is written in `typescript` would you please re-write my statement in `TS` without `any` annotation, btw `data` is a type of `number`

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh why do you even need to type it explicitly? Doesn't TS infer types for you in this case?

Comment: @zerkms story > I used the `navigate` hook and send `data` like this `navigate('/xyz', {state:{data:1})` and want to grab this `data` on page `xyz` so I used `location` hook and able to get the `data` as I show you on my first comment, Now > `TS` is not detecting the `data` which I have passed in another page into the `navigate` which makes sense right? it shows me an error something like this `no destructuring possible on {} empty object`

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh you cannot statically type it, because types are not known compile-time.

Comment: @zerkms is it possible to extend `location` hook `interface/type` so that we can say that to `react` that this `location` will have a property name `data` inside `state`

Comment: Just in case if anyone looking for a more relevant section in the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#unpacking_properties_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter