# Why I can't desctructure value from a target in onChange event?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization

I am trying to desctructure in 1 time my value from my element, but I have to do it in a separated line.. That's not blocking, but really annoying.

What I want to do :

```
    const onChangeValue = ({ target: value}) => {
        onChange({ attribute, indexValue, value });
    };
```

What I need to do :

```
const onChangeValue = ({ target }) => {
        const { value } = target;
        onChange({ attribute, indexValue, value });
    };
```

Anys ideas ? I'm working with React (CRA)

I hope I won't make a question that already have been asked.. cause I search don't find anything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 deep nested object destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622385/es6-deep-nested-object-destructuring)

Comment: I don't understand; the code you posted as "what I need to do" works fine for me. What problem are you having?

Comment: @IceMetalPunk "What I need to do" is what works. "What I want to do" is what he wants to do - but does not work.

Comment: @Bricky Ah, yes, I misread. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

You're 2 snippets aren't equivalent, hence 1 works while the other doesn't. The equivalent of you're second example using parameter destructuring would be

```
const onChangeValue = ({ target: {value}) => {
        onChange({ attribute, indexValue, value });
    };
```

Your first snippet (without the `{}` around `value` is *renaming* `target` to `value`, whereas the curly braces in my snippet specify that `value` is a property in `target`, which is itself a property in the argument.

To clarify, given an argument named `arg`,

- your 1st snippet accesses `arg.target` and assigns it to `value`.
- your 2nd snippet accesses `arg.target`, assigns it to `target`, then assigns `target.value` to `value`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the variable name you don't need to do this.

```
const onChangeValue = ({ target }) => {
    onChange({ attribute, indexValue, target });
};
```

Will work, and you'll end up with the object:

```
onChangeValue = {
    attribute: someValue,  // same value as 'attribute'
    indexValue: someValue, // same value as 'indexValue'
    target: someValue      // same value as 'target'
}
```

If you want to change the name, you can do that without the new variable as well:

```
const onChangeValue = ({ target }) => {
    onChange({ attribute, indexValue, value: target.value });
};
```

In this vase `target` will evaluate to it's value, and you can use a custom key name ("value", in this case), giving you:

```
onChangeValue = {
    attribute: someValue,  // same value as 'attribute'
    indexValue: someValue, // same value as 'indexValue'
    value: target.value    // same value as 'target.value' with key/name 'value'
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. `argument.target.value` (desired behavior) is not the same as `argument.target` (your first snippet).