# How to store an object in context?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, react-router, react-hooks

Storing an object in context doesn't work for me for an unknown reason.

Is it possible to do like this with context?

```
import { createContext } from "react";

export const authContext = createContext({
  auth: {isAuth: false, user: {}},
  setAuth: () => {},
});
```

edit:

```
export const PrivateRoute = ({ path, children }) => {
  const { auth.isAuth } = useContext(authContext);
  return auth.isAuth ? (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Route path={path}>{children}</Route>
    </>
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/login" />
  );
};
```

Comment: Yes, that's possible and we use it a lot in other projects. What's not working for you?

Comment: Okay, but how can I access isAuth? I have tried const { auth.isAuth } = useContext(authContext); @Dominik

Comment: Share your code and I can help you find the issue. There is not enough here to see what you're doing

Comment: `const { auth.isAuth } = useContext(authContext)` is a syntax error. In js this would be this: `const { auth: { isAuth } } = useContext(authContext)`

Comment: Seems strange for me, is there any documentation available? @Dominik

Comment: This is how JavaScript works. [`destructuring assignments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ES6 deep nested object destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622385/es6-deep-nested-object-destructuring)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As cleared up in the comments your destructuring syntax is wrong.
It should be this:

```js
export const PrivateRoute = ({ path, children }) => {
  const { auth: { isAuth } } = useContext(authContext);
  //           ^---- THIS WAS CHANGED
  return isAuth ? (
  //       ^---- AND THIS
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <Route path={path}>{children}</Route>
    </>
  ) : (
    <Redirect to="/login" />
  );
};
```

Read more about it on the [MDN Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) page.