# Destructuring a Object nested inside Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, destructuring

I have the following object structure

```
session: {
  expires: String,
  sessionData: {
    user: Object,
    token: String
  }
}
```

I want to do the destruct in the same line of code that I define these constants that I get from a hook in react.

```js
const [ session, loading ] = useSession();
```

I am currently doing it this way. Is there an alternative?

```js
 const [ session, loading] = useSession();
 const { user } = session.sessionData;
```

I want to know if something like this can be done:

```js
 const [ user: session: {sessionData: user}, loading] = useSession();
```

Comment: It looks like you are implying you want to create a context. Look up how to create context in react. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: What module does `useSession` come from? Does it really return an iterable as implied with your code? (`const [ session, loading ] = useSession();`)

Comment: @GeomanYabes It comes from a library called next-auth and yes, the object is iterable, in the answer to another question I have marked the solution I have found most suitable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### NOTES:

#### 1. This code will error if `sessionData` is `null` or `undefined`:

`const [{sessionData: { user }}, loading] = useSession();`

```js
const useSession = () => [{
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + (3600 * 1000 * 24)),
  sessionData: null
}, false];

const [{ sessionData: {user}}, loading] = useSession();
console.log('user:', user, 'loading:', loading);
```

#### 2. Using the same code, you can't assign an inline default value to fix the `TypeError` described above.

```js
const someData = {
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar'
};

//assign `baz: 'default'` to avoid `TypeError` if `baz` property does not exist
const {foo, bar, baz = 'default'} = someData;
console.log(foo, bar, baz);



//sadly, this doesnt work here.
const useSession = () => [{
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + (3600 * 1000 * 24)),
  sessionData: null
}, false];

const [{ sessionData: {user} = {} }, loading] = useSession();
console.log('user:', user, 'loading:', loading);
```

Maybe I'm missing something but I just can't get it to work using default values. The only way I fixed this is getting `sessionData` first then work on that afterwards while using default values.

```js
const useSession = () => [{
  expires: new Date(Date.now() + (3600 * 1000 * 24)),
  sessionData: null
}, false];

//assign {} to `sessionData` if it is undefined
const [{expires, sessionData = {} }, loading] = useSession();
console.log(sessionData); //null

//above default value will still fail if sessionData is null.
// to fix, coalesce to {}
const {user, token} = sessionData || {}; 
console.log(user, token);
```

#### 3. Be careful with "Gotcha's"

You may have noticed the `|| {}` code in the above code even though we added a default value to `sessionData`. This is because default values only apply to `undefined`, not `null`s.

On the same note, it is better to add a coalesce on `useSession` too since your code will break if `useSession()` returns a `null` or `undefined`.

```js
const useSession = () => { return null; };

//assign {} to `sessionData` if it is undefined
console.log(useSession()); //null

// useSession()[0], a.k.a. session is undefined
// need to add default since we are destructuring `sessionData` from `session`
const [{ sessionData } = {}, loading] = useSession() || [];

//// this also works but it assigns `sessionData = {}`
//const [{ sessionData = {} } = {}, loading] = useSession() || [];
// wont be doing that since we are proving the next point:

//above default value will still fail since `sessionData` will be undefined
// to fix, coalesce to {}
const {user, token} = sessionData || {}; 
console.log(user, token);
```

### Finally

Getting `sessionData` and/or `expires` (a.k.a `session`) first actually isn't bad at all since you may also want to get the other properties, i.e, `session.expires`, `sessionData.token`, etc. It also allows you to fix the Gotchas mentioned above.

This [**awesome article** *(Object destructuring best practice in Javascript)*](https://crunchtech.medium.com/object-destructuring-best-practice-in-javascript-9c8794699a0d) discusses the above notes in-depth. Take time to read.

Answer (score 1):

You can destructure like this to set the `user` variable:

```
const [{sessionData: { user }}, loading] = useSession();
```

Comment: I've solved it this way before, I think it's the right way!

Answer (score 0):

The object structure you provided is not valid. I came to get `user` and `token` with following construct:

```js
var a = {
      session: {
        expires: '1d',
        sessionData: {
          user: 'myUser',
          token: 'token'
        }
      }
    }
    
    var {session: {sessionData: {user, token}, expires}} = a
    
    console.log(user, token, expires) // 'myUser token 1d'
```

For more info, see [ES6 deep nested object destructuring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40622385/es6-deep-nested-object-destructuring)

Comment: The structure of the object is fine, I just solved this problem in the following way, anyway thanks for your answer.

const [ {sessionData: {user}}, loading] = useSession();