# TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).map is not a function

Tags: javascript

I get the error: `TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).map is not a function`

What I want to do is send the data to a server, and store it. It's not working, no fix helps me. The error states that something is up with createWorker.js:191:15, but I'm not sure on what createWorker is. I'm new to JS, so please help me out!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/tesseract.js@4.0.2/dist/tesseract.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const video = document.createElement("video");
        const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        let imageData;
  
        navigator.mediaDevices
          .getDisplayMedia({ video: true })
          .then(stream => {
            video.srcObject = stream;
            video.play();
  
            setInterval(() => {
              ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
              imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
              processImage();
            }, 1000);
          });
  
        const processImage = () => {
          Tesseract.recognize(imageData, {
            lang: "eng"
          })
            .then(result => {
              const text = result.text;
              sendToServer(text.split("\n"));
            })
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
        };
  
        const sendToServer = text => {
          fetch("https://example.com/text_parse", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ textArray: text })
          })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => console.log("Success:", data))
            .catch(err => console.error(err));
        };
      </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Scan for text that's onscreen, and send it to a server (in this case, example.com/text_parse)

Answer (score 0):

Looking briefly I believe the problem is with this line:

```js
const text = result.text;
```

There's an example from the [docs](https://github.com/naptha/tesseract.js#tesseractjs) which shows:

```js
).then(({ data: { text } }) => {
```

which is using [nested object destructuring syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40622439/7978627) so you would likely need something like this line to replace the one mentioned earlier:

```js
const text = result.data.text;
```

It's likely when you're trying to do something with the assumed array response, it's not actually an array. You could just try logging `text` to the console to see what it looks like, and if it's what you expect.

As a side note this example would benefit greatly from [async await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) syntax, which I am personally a HUGE fan of, really flattens things out. Hence my screen-name